# render_template() cannot find template located in blueprint folder

Tags: python, flask

The following is a part of my setup in a flask application, using Flask-Blueprints, where `reports` is a blueprint:

```
app
├── __init__.py
└── /reports
    ├── /templates
    │   └── /reports
    │       └── reports.html
    ├── __init__.py
    └── views.py
```

This is my `app/reports/__init.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

reports_bp = Blueprint('reports', __name__)

from app.reports import views
```

And this is how I register the reports blueprint within `app/__init__.py` (notice especially how I specify the location of my template folder as `'templates'`):

```
...
from app.reports import reports_bp
app.register_blueprint(reports_bp, url_prefix='/reports',  template_folder='templates')
...
```

Finally I have a view function in `app/reports/views.py` that looks something like this:

```
@reports_bp.route('/')
def reports():

    ...

    return render_template('reports/reports.html', ...)
```

`render_template` however doesn't find my `reports.html` template, and when I enable the `EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING` config variable I get this feedback:

```
[2020-03-11 14:40:21,966] INFO in debughelpers: Locating template "reports/reports.html":
    1: trying loader of application "app"
       class: jinja2.loaders.FileSystemLoader
       encoding: 'utf-8'
       followlinks: False
       searchpath:
         - /path_to_my_app/app/templates
       -> no match
    2: trying loader of blueprint "restplus_doc" (flask_restplus.apidoc)
       class: jinja2.loaders.FileSystemLoader
       encoding: 'utf-8'
       followlinks: False
       searchpath:
         - /path_to_my_app/my_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restplus/templates
       -> no match
Error: the template could not be found.
  The template was looked up from an endpoint that belongs to the blueprint "reports".
  Maybe you did not place a template in the right folder?
  See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/#templates
```

The first searchpath is to be expected, but **why is the second searchpath from within a site-package folder inside my virtualenv, to which the postfix `/templates` is uselessly attached?**  Shouldn't the second searchpath be the blueprint folder `reports`?

I am using VS Code and running this in debugger mode.  My installed Flask is version 1.0.2.

EDIT: Changing the `template_folder` when registering the blueprint to something else, like `'reports/templates'` doesn't change searchpath number 2.  Which gives me the hint that some other blueprint is bullying my blueprint and controlling where render_template searches.

EDIT 2: **The real problem here was that a loader was not created for my blueprint.**  Loader nr. 2 belongs to another blueprint  I was unaware of when posting the question and is not relevant to my issue. See posted answer for more details.

Comment: It is confusing that you're using package references instead of relative references in your subpackage.  Does changing this make any difference? `from app.reports import views` vs `from . import views`.  The reason for your edit is that flask searches all templates folders, including the extensions to it.

Comment: Hi @TheIncorrigible1 and thanks for your comment! There was really no reason for using the package reference other than that's the way it was done in the tutorial I was following.  Unfortunately, changing to a relative reference did not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly, the `template_folder='templates'` bit is supposed to be included as a parameter when the blueprint is initialized instead of when it is registered like I had been doing.

So now I initialize the blueprint like this in `app/reports/__init.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

reports_bp = Blueprint('reports', __name__, template_folder='templates')

from app.reports import views
```

and I no longer need to specify anything about the template folder when registering the blueprint, see my updated bit of code from `app/__init__.py`:

```
...
from app.reports import reports_bp
app.register_blueprint(reports_bp, url_prefix='/reports')
...
```

Just to show that there has now been added an new jinja loader, this is now printed when the template is rendered:

```
[2020-03-12 13:19:54,870] INFO in debughelpers: Locating template "reports/reports.html":
    1: trying loader of application "app"
       class: jinja2.loaders.FileSystemLoader
       encoding: 'utf-8'
       followlinks: False
       searchpath:
         - /path_to_my_app/app/templates
       -> no match
    2: trying loader of blueprint "restplus_doc" (flask_restplus.apidoc)
       class: jinja2.loaders.FileSystemLoader
       encoding: 'utf-8'
       followlinks: False
       searchpath:
         - /path_to_my_app/ankappenv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restplus/templates
       -> no match
    3: trying loader of blueprint "reports" (app.reports)
       class: jinja2.loaders.FileSystemLoader
       encoding: 'utf-8'
       followlinks: False
       searchpath:
         - /path_to_my_app/app/reports/templates
       -> found ('/path_to_my_app/app/reports/templates/reports/reports.html')
```

Here you can see that a third loader has been added, and that one searches the specified `/app/reports/templates/` path correctly, where it finds the template.